# Distinction between [facebook-chat] and [facebook-messenger]

Tags: support, tags

I don’t use either (both? – it?) but am curious at the distinction between [facebook-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-chat):

> Facebook chat is the instant chat messaging system by Facebook.

and [facebook-messenger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-messenger):

> The instant messaging service, once "Facebook Chat", that includes transfer of audio and video content. It is distinct from the main Facebook app, for which there are several tags, including [facebook-messages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-messages) with which this should not be confused.

Is it really only whether or not on a hand-held device and if so is that made clear enough (if necessary)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a distinction. I think the former should be a synonym of the latter.

Let's not forget about [facebook-messages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-messages). The tag wiki tries to make a distinction, but it's obviously not very clear.