# Please make [facebook-chat] a synonym of [facebook-messenger]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Ref: [Distinction between [facebook-chat] and [facebook-messenger]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4369/distinction-between-facebook-chat-and-facebook-messenger)

The A there includes:

> I don't think there is a distinction. I think the former should be a synonym of the latter.

It has been upvoted and not downvoted and has been up for over a month.

It is impractical to retag ([121 instances](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-chat)) and very few users are eligible even to make/support the synonym suggestion.

<sub>Possibly the tag wiki should be transferred.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done

```
updating post history, 141 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 121 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 118 rows affected
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected
updating DocTags, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, new count: 180
tag remapping of [facebook-messenger] and [facebook-chat] complete!
remapping 1 synonyms
5 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
37 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym facebook-chat -> facebook-messenger was approved!
```